# Compute the hyperbolic angle subtended to the origin by the unit hyperbola through (ct, x) = (0, 1)

Tags: general-relativity

I'm trying to find the angle subtended by the unit hyperbola through the point $(ct,x)=(1,0)$. I think that I should be integrating something, but I'm not sure how to set it up. I've been trying to think of this as it would be related to a unit circle, where we would have $R=1$ and then the following
$$
\int_0^{\theta_{0}} R^2(\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta)d\theta=R^2\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta=(1)(2\pi)=2\pi
$$
So the angle subtended would just be $2\pi$. I know that $1=\cosh^2 x-\sinh^2 x,$ but as I'm only interested in the right hyperbola, I'm not sure I can use the same trick. I do believe this is related to the total proper time along the hyperbola. Beyond this, I'm stuck, and I feel I'm going about this the wrong way. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The hyperbolic angle subtended by the entire hyperbola is infinite. Physically, this is related to the *rapidity* of the speed of light being infinite. But how to answer this depends on the starting point of "hyperbolic angle"--can one start with the parametrization $(ct,x) = (\cosh\eta,\sinh\eta)$, which makes this trivial, or must one relate to the area of a hyperbolic sector?

Comment: I've actually tried there, but I haven't had any luck.

Comment: Honestly, I think the parametrization would work.. I want the area between the asymptotes on the right hyperbola and the the hyperbola.

Comment: How, exactly, do I use the parametrization?

Answer (score 0):

> How, exactly, do I use the parametrization?

If you let $(x,y) = (r\cosh\eta,r\sinh\eta)$ and consider the Jacobian determinant, you can show that the area element transforms as
$$\mathrm{d}A = \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y =  r\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\eta\text{.}$$
Alternatively, you can transform the metric $\mathrm{d}s^2 = \mathrm{d}x^2 + \mathrm{d}y^2$ directly and get its determinant for $\mathrm{d}A^2$, but that's slightly more work.

Integrating $\mathrm{d}A$ between the asymptotes involves $\eta\in(-\infty,+\infty)$, and so obviously gives infinite area.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with:

We begin by first parametrizing our coordinate system with the following transformations. Let
$$
x=\cosh\alpha,\\
ct=\sinh\alpha.
$$
Then, from the unit hyperbola, we want the right-hand hyperbola. The area swept out between the hyperbola and its asymptote is given by
$$
\int_0^{\alpha_0}\left(\cosh^2\alpha-\sinh^2\alpha\right)\text{d}\alpha=\left.\alpha\right|_{\alpha=0}^{\alpha_0}=\alpha_0. 
$$
Hence, as $\alpha_0\in(-\infty,\infty)$, the angle subtended to the origin is $\alpha=\infty$.